Center of factors of a finite $p$-group, obtained from minimal normal subgroups
throughout studying a  paper about finite $p$-groups,
I have a challenge as follows,
Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group, where $p$ is odd and $Z(G)$ is non-cyclic.
($Z(G)$ denotes the center of $G$). Also let $G$ satisfies the following two properties
(a) There exists a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that for any $x\in G$,
if $\langle x\rangle \ntriangleleft G$, then $\langle x,N\rangle \ntriangleleft G$.
(b) For any minimal normal subgroup $V$ of $G$ and the subgroup $U$ of $G$, where
$\displaystyle\frac{U}{V}:=Z(\frac{G}{V})$, any cyclic subgroup of $U$ is normal in $G$.
Question: Does there exists  a minimal normal subgroup $T$ of $G$, such that
$\displaystyle Z(\frac{G}{T})=\frac{Z(G)}{T}$?
Some examples in GAP library, show that may be the answer is yes,
even if for $p$-groups, which only satisfies the property (a).
The following observations, which is based on our assumptions may be helpful,
(1) $U=\{g\in G | [g,x]\in V,  \forall x\in G\}$, where $[g,x]:=g^{-1}x^{-1}gx$. By (b) $U$ is abelian.
(2) For any $u\in U$, we have $u^p\in Z(G)$, because $[u^p,g]=[u,g]^p=1$, for all $g\in G$.
This shows that $\displaystyle\frac{U}{Z(G)}$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group.
(3) By (b) we have For any $u\in U$,
$V\leq \langle u\rangle $ or $u\in Z(G)$.
(4) For any $u\in U$, it follows that $\displaystyle \frac{G}{C_{G}(u)}$ is embedded in $\displaystyle Aut(\langle u\rangle)$,
because by property (b) we have $\langle u\rangle \triangleleft G$. Therefore $ G^{\prime} \leq C_{G}(u)$,
where $G^{\prime}:=\langle [x,g]| x,g \in G\rangle$ is the derived subgroup of $G$
and $\displaystyle Aut(\langle u\rangle)$ is the automorphism group of $\langle u\rangle$.
(5) Take $gN\in Z(G/N)$ and note that $\langle g,N\rangle \triangleleft G$. Property (a) implies that
$\langle g\rangle \triangleleft G$. Now if $|g|=p$, then $g\in Z(G)$ and so $gN\in Z(G)/N$.
Update: After an attempt I find another restriction on the subgroups $U$ as $\exp(U)=p^2$.
Now according to the examples in GAP library, may be the minimal normal subgroup
whose generator is the product of all generators of minimal normal subgroups of $G$
could have the desired role in my question.
Any Answer or comment will be greatly appreciated.

I do not understand "if and only if" in (3). The group $\langle u\rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup of $U$, so $\langle u\rangle \triangleleft G$ by (b).

Many thank's. I corrected (3) and added an updating of question.

Also I added an updating of question.
